# Duplicating vector along an arbitrary number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I want to repeat a `1D-array` along the dimensions of another array, knowing that this number of dimensions can change.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
to_repeat = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)
base_array = np.random.random((24, 60)) ## this one can have more than two dimensions.

final_array = np.array([[to_repeat for i in range(base_array.shape[0])] for j in range(base_array.shape[1])]).T
print(final_array.shape)
# >>> (10, 24, 60)
```

How can this be extended to an array `base_array` with an arbitrary number of dimensions?
Possibly using `numpy` vectorized functions in order to avoid loops?

---

EDIT (bigger picture):

`base_array` is in fact of shape `(10, 24, 60)` (if we stick to this example), where the coordinates along the first dimension are the vector `to_repeat`.

I'm looking for the minimum along the first dimension of `base_array`, and create the array of corresponding coordinates, here of shape `(24, 60)`.

Comment: What are you using this for?  Because you almost certainly want to broadcast `to_repeat` instead of actually making `final_array`.

Comment: See my edited question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `final_array`, you can get the result you want by:

```
to_repeat[base_array.argmin(0)]
```

Comment: This return `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 18 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10`

Comment: You need to provide runnable code that clearly shows your input shapes and expected output.  If `base_array.shape = (10, 24, 60)` as you say, `argmin(0)` should not return 18.

Comment: Sorry I misstyped when I ran your answer. It indeed works perfectly.